# Identical queries and data returning different results - Something to do with date?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have two databases- dev and staging. When I run this query in the two of them, I get the same thing in both-

```
SELECT COUNT(s.id)
FROM app_session_history s
WHERE DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 6 HOUR) < NOW();
```

But when I run this, I get different results in each-

```
SELECT COUNT(s.id)
FROM app_session_history s
JOIN app_project_usage_history p
ON s.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 6 HOUR) < p.created_at;
```

I know the data is exactly the same because I import them both directly from production immediately before running. And the schemas are the same as well. I copy and paste the code, so that is the same as well.

The loginTime values are stored in Mountain Time and this is part of a bigger project to get them converted to UTC, which is what the created_at columns are in (this is just a sliver of the code that was adjusted to make sense here).

When I run the queries below, they all just say "SYSTEM" in staging and dev, but I'm pretty sure staging is in UTC and dev is in Mountain.

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
SELECT @@session.time_zone;
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I'm guessing the query is somehow timezone dependent... Is there a way to change that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you have a mix of DATETIME and TIMESTAMP columns. [TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html) columns are stored in UTC and converted to/from session tz on the way in and out. Have you checked the system timezone of the two environments?

Comment: @user1191247 That's good to know, I had no idea. Thank you! And I did just check the system timezone- on dev it's MDT and on staging it's UTC.

Comment: @courtneymickelsen you should post as an answer (it's OK to answer your own questions) that the two machines had different system times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two machines turned out to have different system timezones, which can affect the way TIMESTAMP values are processed. I am still working on making the query non-timezone dependent, but I posted that as [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75977895/14998487).