# Make a MySQL Query non timezone-dependent

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I have a query that I am trying to run on my development and staging databases. The problems is that the system timezone for the two is different. Development is in Mountain Time and Staging is in UTC. In my query I am trying to match up login times with the time that someone accessed a project on our website. The problem is that the login time in the session table is TIMESTAMP and stored in Mountain Time (really wish this wasn't the case), and the created_at in the project usage table is DATETIME and using UTC. I recently learned that TIMESTAMP values are converted to and from the system timezone on their ways in and out, so the query returns different values when I run it on dev vs staging. Does anyone know how I can convert this so that I can run the same code on both databases and have it do the same thing regardless of system timezone?

I want to add two new values, the login time and the session id that is related to that instance of accessing a project. I convert the login time either 6 or 7 hours depending on daylight savings time dates, and find the most recent login for a given user before the project was accessed (as long as it's within 12 hours). Then I assign it that id and then add a time for the login converted to UTC based on the same things. It works great in development right now (so on the Mountain Time system).

Here is my code-

```
use development;

-- Creating the new columns
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
ALTER TABLE app_project_usage_history ADD COLUMN session_login_time DATETIME;
ALTER TABLE app_project_usage_history ADD COLUMN session_id INT(10) NOT NULL;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;

-- Resetting session_id values
-- SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
-- UPDATE app_project_usage_history p
-- SET p.session_id = 0;
-- UPDATE app_project_usage_history p
-- SET p.session_login_time = NULL;
-- SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;

--  Setting session id values for winter months (-7 hours)
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE app_project_usage_history p
SET p.session_id = (
  SELECT MAX(s.id)
  FROM app_session_history s
  WHERE s.user_id = p.user_id
    AND DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 7 HOUR) < p.created_at
    AND DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 7 HOUR) > DATE_SUB(p.created_at, INTERVAL 12 HOUR) 
    AND (p.created_at < DATE('2018-03-11 02:00:01')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2018-11-04 02:00:01') AND DATE('2019-03-10 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2019-11-03 02:00:01') AND DATE('2020-03-08 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2020-11-01 02:00:01') AND DATE('2021-03-14 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2021-11-07 02:00:01') AND DATE('2022-03-13 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2022-11-06 02:00:01') AND DATE('2023-03-12 02:00:00')
    )
) WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM app_session_history s
  WHERE s.user_id = p.user_id
    AND DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 7 HOUR) < p.created_at
    AND DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 7 HOUR) > DATE_SUB(p.created_at, INTERVAL 12 HOUR) 
    AND (p.created_at < DATE('2018-03-11 02:00:01')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2018-11-04 02:00:01') AND DATE('2019-03-10 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2019-11-03 02:00:01') AND DATE('2020-03-08 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2020-11-01 02:00:01') AND DATE('2021-03-14 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2021-11-07 02:00:01') AND DATE('2022-03-13 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2022-11-06 02:00:01') AND DATE('2023-03-12 02:00:00')
    )
);
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;

--  Setting session id values for summer months (-6 hours)
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE app_project_usage_history p
SET p.session_id = (
  SELECT MAX(s.id)
  FROM app_session_history s
  WHERE s.user_id = p.user_id
    AND DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 6 HOUR) < p.created_at
    AND DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 6 HOUR) > DATE_SUB(p.created_at, INTERVAL 12 HOUR) 
    AND (p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2018-03-11 02:00:01') AND DATE('2018-11-04 02:00:00')
      OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2019-03-10 02:00:01') AND DATE('2019-11-03 02:00:00')
      OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2020-03-08 02:00:01') AND DATE('2020-11-01 02:00:00')
      OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2021-03-14 02:00:01') AND DATE('2021-11-07 02:00:00')
      OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2022-03-13 02:00:01') AND DATE('2022-11-06 02:00:00')
      OR p.created_at > DATE('2023-03-12 02:00:01')
    )
) WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM app_session_history s
  WHERE s.user_id = p.user_id
    AND DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 6 HOUR) < p.created_at
    AND DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 6 HOUR) > DATE_SUB(p.created_at, INTERVAL 12 HOUR) 
    AND (p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2018-03-11 02:00:01') AND DATE('2018-11-04 02:00:00')
      OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2019-03-10 02:00:01') AND DATE('2019-11-03 02:00:00')
      OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2020-03-08 02:00:01') AND DATE('2020-11-01 02:00:00')
      OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2021-03-14 02:00:01') AND DATE('2021-11-07 02:00:00')
      OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2022-03-13 02:00:01') AND DATE('2022-11-06 02:00:00')
      OR p.created_at > DATE('2023-03-12 02:00:01')
    )
);
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;

-- Setting session time values for winter months (-7)
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE app_project_usage_history p
INNER JOIN app_session_history s
ON p.session_id = s.id
SET p.session_login_time = DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
WHERE p.created_at < DATE('2018-03-11 02:00:01')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2018-11-04 02:00:01') AND DATE('2019-03-10 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2019-11-03 02:00:01') AND DATE('2020-03-08 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2020-11-01 02:00:01') AND DATE('2021-03-14 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2021-11-07 02:00:01') AND DATE('2022-03-13 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2022-11-06 02:00:01') AND DATE('2023-03-12 02:00:00');

-- Setting session time values for summer months (-6)
UPDATE app_project_usage_history p
LEFT JOIN app_session_history s
ON p.session_id = s.id
SET p.session_login_time = DATE_SUB(s.loginTime, INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
WHERE p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2018-03-11 02:00:01') AND DATE('2018-11-04 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2019-03-10 02:00:01') AND DATE('2019-11-03 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2020-03-08 02:00:01') AND DATE('2020-11-01 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2021-03-14 02:00:01') AND DATE('2021-11-07 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at BETWEEN DATE('2022-03-13 02:00:01') AND DATE('2022-11-06 02:00:00')
   OR p.created_at > DATE('2023-03-12 02:00:01');
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;


-- Helpful debugging queries
SELECT * FROM app_project_usage_history WHERE user_id = 133;
SELECT * FROM app_session_history WHERE user_id = 133;
SELECT * FROM app_project_usage_history ORDER BY created_at DESC;
SELECT * FROM app_session_history ORDER BY loginTime DESC;
SELECT * FROM app_project_usage_history WHERE session_id = 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) as project_count FROM app_project_usage_history;
SELECT COUNT(*) as session_count FROM app_session_history;
SELECT COUNT(*) as unchanged_rows FROM app_project_usage_history WHERE session_id = 0;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use `CONVERT_TZ(login_time,'SYSTEM','00:00')` to convert the login time from the system time zone to UTC? (See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).)

Comment: Personally I prefer storing any datetime data in DB in UTC and converting to/from client-related timezone at a client side.

Comment: @Serg I would definitely prefer that. Unfortunately this project has been around for years before I started working on it, and the previous developer didn't store them that way. That's part of why I am trying to convert them, so we have a loginTime stored in UTC as well.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen That's a great idea! I just tried it, but the function won't take 'SYSTEM' as an argument. It also won't take @@system_time_zone because that returns 'MDT', and the function requires the longer form of the timezone ('America/Denver' instead of 'MDT')

Comment: Something like `CONVERT_TZ(login_time,case when @@system_time_zone = 'MDT' then 'America/Denver' else 'UTC' end,'00:00')`? After all, you want to cover only two time zones.